# Arm EL0 Address Translation

Tags: linux, arm, memory-address

I want to translate a virtual user level address (EL0) to a physical address.

Arm provides an instruction `AT` to translate a virtual address to a physical address. This instruction should be called by privileged level (EL1), so I write a linux kernel module to execute this instruction. I pass a user level address (EL0) `virt_addr` through `ioctl()` to kernel module, and execute instruction `AT`.

According to the [instruction manual](https://armv8-ref.codingbelief.com/en/chapter_d4/d42_11_address_translation_instructions.html), I execute the instruction by this way:

```
// S1E0R: S1 means stage 1, E0 means EL0 and R means read.
asm volatile("AT S1E0R, %[_addr_]" :: [_addr_]"r"(virt_addr));

// Register PAR_EL1 stores the translation result.
asm volatile("MRS %0, PAR_EL1": "=r"(phys_addr));
```

However, the value of register `PAR_EL1`, i.e. stored in `phys_addr`, is `0x80b` (or `0b100000001011`), which is not a correct result.

Then I found a [manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2020-12/AArch64-Registers/PAR-EL1--Physical-Address-Register?lang=en#fieldset_1-6_1) about register `PAR_EL1`.

According to the manual, bit[0] is 1 means a fault occurs on the execution of an Address translation instruction.

bits[6:1] is Fault Status Code (FST). My FST is `0b000101`. The manual tell me that the error information is: **Translation fault, level 1**.

I don't know the fault reason.

My cpu is Cortex-A53, and operating system is Linux-4.14.59.

Comment: Firstly, it is clear that you are missing a _context synchronisation_ event between the system-register altering `AT` instruction, and read-back through `PAR`. This is an explicit case that requires synchronisation as explained in "Synchronization of changes to system control registers". The tl;dr is that you need an `isb` between the two instructions. However, that might not be your main problem. Are you sure the userspace address has an existing translation at EL0?